# Как сделать, чтобы при удалении одного блока второй растягивался на всю ширину?

Tags: css3, html5, css

Здраствуйте!

Подскажите, как реализовать, чтобы при удалении одной из колонок оставшаяся колонка заняла 100% от блока контента.

Заранее спасибо.

http://jsfiddle.net/uze4acyz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае отлично подходит табличная верстка.

```
<div class="content">
    <article>left</article>
    <aside>right</aside> 
</div>
```

---

```
.content{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    height: 200px; /* Такой же эффект как и у min-height */
    margin-top: 20px; /* Demo */
}
aside{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 150px; /* У второго столбца ширина рассчитается автоматически */
    background: #B2033B;
}
article{
    display: table-cell;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/uze4acyz/1/)**